# IBM AppScan - Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie

Tags: jsf, cookies, primefaces, bluemix-app-scan

We have got an Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie issue for primefaces.download based on IBM App Scan DSAT test.

*Primefaces version is 7.0*

Sample Example : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

primefaces.download -- this cookies is set when we download a file

We already have session-config in the web.xml , but when i check in chrome the primefaces.download cookie is not set as http-only and secured .

Is there anything else required to be done when running it on JBOSS 7.2?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

..........

<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

[image]

Updated :
**Issue raised**
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pull Request to fix the issue in 9.0-SNAPSHOT has been submitted.

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/6041